# QStandardPaths.writableLocation returns invalid result in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In `__main__.py` file,

```
QtCore.qDebug(QStandardPaths.writableLocation(QStandardPaths.AppLocalDataLocation))
```

outputs

```
/home/admin/.local/share/__main__.py
```

instead of just

```
/home/admin/.local/share
```

Why does it append `__main__.py` at the end? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug, it is correct.

If the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#StandardLocation-enum) is reviewed:

> **macOS**:
>
> `"~/Library/Application Support/<APPNAME>"`, `"/Library/Application Support/<APPNAME>"`. `"<APPDIR>/../Resources"`
>
> **Windows**
>
> `"C:/Users/<USER>/AppData/Local/<APPNAME>"`, `"C:/ProgramData/<APPNAME>"`, `"<APPDIR>"`, `"<APPDIR>/data"`, `"<APPDIR>/data/<APPNAME>"`
>
> **Linux**
>
> AppLocalDataLocation  `"~/.local/share/<APPNAME>"`, `"/usr/local/share/<APPNAME>"`, `"/usr/share/<APPNAME>"`

It is noted that all end with `<APPNAME>`, if a name is not established it will take the name of the main file:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    qDebug("applicationName: "+ app.applicationName())
    qDebug(QStandardPaths.writableLocation(QStandardPaths.AppLocalDataLocation))
    app.setApplicationName("MyApp")
    qDebug("applicationName: " + app.applicationName())
    qDebug(QStandardPaths.writableLocation(QStandardPaths.AppLocalDataLocation))
```

Output:

```
applicationName: main.py
/home/eyllanesc/.local/share/main.py
applicationName: MyApp
/home/eyllanesc/.local/share/MyApp
```

Comment: Thanks. I should be careful while reading the docs next time. :)